# Getting ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Some reporters are still unsynced: WdioMochawesomeReporter

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, mochawesome

This is the error I am seeing when try to integrate mochawesome report to Appium with wdio:
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Some reporters are still unsynced: WdioMochawesomeReporter
[0-0]     at Timeout.<anonymous> (file:///Users/murali.gunnam@abc.com/qa-mobile-test-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/reporter.js:111:35)
[0-0]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
[0-0]     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

Comment: This is my wdio.config --  reporters: ['mochawesome'], mochawesomeOpts: {includeScreenshots:true, screenshotUseRelativePath:true},reporterOptions: {outputDir: './', //json file will be written to this directory mochawesome_filename:''  //will default to wdiomochawesome.json if no name is provided},

Comment: i have these dependencies: "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5" "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "webdriverio": "^4.14.4"